# Is it possible to wrap/configure a mock reference with a testing::NiceMock<> equivalence?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a complex mock class that can expose other (necessary) mock instances just by reference. Since there are circular dependencies I have to solve these, using forward declarations and put implementations to concrete compilation units (to see the completed class declarations).

When writing testcases, I want to behave these instances like `testing::NiceMock<T>`, but I can't see a direction how to achieve this.

Replacing the exposed references with `testing::NiceMock<ExposedMockClass>*` or `testing::NiceMock<ExposedMockClass>&` doesn't work since `ExposedMockClass` is just forward declared at that point.

Is there a technique available with gmock on board utilities to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NiceMock<T>` inherits from `T`, so the only thing that needs to know it's a NiceMock is the thing that creates it. From that point onwards, you can deal with it as `T`.

For example, it's perfectly ok to do this:

```
ExposedMockClass* mockObject = new testing::NiceMock<ExposedMockClass>();
EXPECT_CALL(*mockObject, exampleFunction(_,_));
```

Comment: Ahhh, didn't think that way round!! Yes, I want to behave the instance like that by default, rather than injecting this externally. Will try and come back ...